# android:Quick search

Tags: android

I want implement the search box some what like twitter and IO Conference schedule app.There will be search icon in top bar,when click there will be search box to enter the user query then query will be submit to activity,can any please help me out with steps how to do it
need to do in 2.2
  Please check this out here http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Twitter-for-Android-Search-120x200.jpg

Thank you.